# Connect to bluetooth device from a listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth, connection

I was trying to connect to a paired bluetooth device from a list view, but i cant seem to get it right. My code seems fine, but it does nothing when i run it on my phone. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.io.IOError;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InvalidObjectException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Devices extends ListActivity {

     private ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
     private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
         btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
         getPairedDevices();
     }


    private void getPairedDevices() {

Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if(pairedDevices.size()>0){
    for (BluetoothDevice device :pairedDevices){
        String name = device.getName();
        btArrayAdapter.add(name);
    }
 }

 setListAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
   }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

Set<BluetoothDevice> device = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
//System.out.println(device.getClass());

Thread ConnectThread = new Thread();
ConnectThread.start();


   }

   public class ConnectThread extends Thread{

private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); 

public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device){
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    mmDevice = device;

    try{
        tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e){}
    mmSocket = tmp;
}

public void run(){
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    try{
        mmSocket.connect();
    }catch (IOException connectException){

        try{
            mmSocket.close();
        }catch (IOException closeException){}
        return;

    }

    //Work to manage connection
}

public void cancel(){
    try{
        mmSocket.close();
    }catch (IOException e){}
}
 }





}
```

Comment: Sorry about how messy the code is.

Comment: i don't get what you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you for asking this i got solution from your question.

Answer (score 2):

In your onCreate() method, you need to set the adapter for your ListView.

i.e.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    setListAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
    getPairedDevices();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that, but it made no difference. The device chosen in the list view does not connect.

Comment: Help anyone? Please? Im really stuck on this. :(

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake in the code. The ListAdapter shoud be set before adding the information to it. Also, in your getPairedDevices() method, after the for loop completes, you should refresh the listview.

Comment: @user2085316 : not really, setListAdapter is done in getPairedDevices

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice it due to the poor formatting.

At any rate, @OP, it looks like the list should be populating correctly. What exactly do you mean by "it does nothing?"